# scrollable text in detail cards of list of items

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

I am trying to add a scrollable textview in to my cards.
Looking through the `AdvancedLayout` example I noticed that I have to either comment out `onKey`, `onTab` event listeners or call the super class listeners to make it work in the list items.
But I was not able to make it work in the detail item. I assume it has something to do with the `sendTextViewLayoutId` method of `SmartEyeglassControlUtils` class. I am using it as well on some places in the code but could not get it work on the textview of the detail card.

Any suggestions?

Cannot this be made as simple as setting some attribute on the TextView in layout.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

With `sendTextViewLayoutId` you define, which `TextView` will be scrollable. You call it, after your layout is sent to be shown.

Try to set the `TextView` width and height relatively to your layout, instead of wrap_content. Please let me know, if that helped.

Comment: I am actually doing it as it is done in the AdvancedLayout sample. With hardcoded height and width and calling sendTextViewLayoutId at as much places as I can. But no luck.